# Decode and flatten nested json into an Elm record

Tags: elm

I just started learning Elm and I have hit a roadblock. Looking for some help from this awesome community.

I'm looking to decode a nested json and pulling in a particular nested value into a elm record.

The json source looks like this:

```
 {
    "id": 672761,
    "modified": "2018-02-12T00:53:04",
    "slug": "Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https://awesomelinkhere.com",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis."
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.",
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "Donec sed odio dui.",
    }
}
```

and I want to pull apart the `title.rendered` and `content.rendered` into a field in my model , the model looks like so:

```
type alias Post =
    { id : Int
    , published : String
    , title : String
    , link : String
    , slug : String
    , excerpt : String
    }
```

my naive decoder looks like this

```
postDecoder : Decoder Post
postDecoder =
    Decode.map6 Post
        (field "id" Decode.int)
        (field "modified" Decode.string)
        (field "title" Decode.string)
        (field "link" Decode.string)
        (field "slug" Decode.string)
        (field "excerpt" Decode.string)
```

Comment: Add your update as an answer and mark it resolved. It makes it easier for others to find this information later.

Comment: updated the update!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

As it usually happens I found the answer as soon as I posted this. I reviewed the [Json.Decode documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#at) and stumbled on the `at` function

my working decoder looks like this now

```
postDecoder : Decoder Post
postDecoder =
    Decode.map6 Post
        (field "id" Decode.int)
        (field "modified" Decode.string)
        (at [ "title", "rendered" ] Decode.string)
        (field "link" Decode.string)
        (field "slug" Decode.string)
        (at [ "excerpt", "rendered" ] Decode.string)
```

Comment: the immediacy of the answer to oneself after the question has been thoughtfully formed confounds me. i now have all i need from elm's decoding. bravo.